# Equation of motion of $p$ in axis.

Tags: euclidean-geometry, circles

[image]

How should I proceed to find the equation of motion of $p$ in the $X,Y$-axis?
For the $x,y$-axis it's trivial, we just have the equation of a circle, but how should I find the other ones?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: write motion equations of $p$ respect to $A$, then motion equations of $A$ respect to $O$. Then sum.

Comment: With respect to $A$ we just get the motion equations of a circle. But how should I proceed further? I mean how should I get the motion equations of $A$ respect to $O$

Comment: Hint: you know that in the $xy$-frame the location of $P$ can be described as function of the angle $\alpha$, and that the location of $A$ in the $XY$-frame is a function of the angle $\theta$. The relative angle between the $xy$ and $XY$ frame allows you to express $P$ also in the $XY$-frame. The last thing you need is a relation between $\alpha$ and $\theta$. Although not mentioned, I assume that the problem specifies a slip-free rolling of the inner circle with respect to the outer one? So I suggest looking a for what angles $\alpha$, $\theta$ the point $P$ lies again on the outer circle.